# ¿Como solucionar java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present?

Tags: java, excepciones

Tengo este error donde dice que no tiene valor la variable txHash o el inputData pero tiene guardo las variables y eso lo puedo ver por el 
**System.out.println("txHash==> " + txHash + "| InputData==> " + inputData + "\n\n");**

```
    public ArrayList ObtenerByHash(Web3j web3, String txHash) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException, DecoderException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, ClassNotFoundException, URISyntaxException, JSONException {
        Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
        String inputData = null;
```

`Optional<Transaction> tx = web3.ethGetTransactionByHash(txHash).send().getTransaction();

    if (tx.isPresent()) {
        inputData = tx.get().getInput();
    }

    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    ConsumirApiRest api = new ConsumirApiRest();

    try {

        System.out.println("txHash==> " + txHash + "| InputData==> " + inputData + "\n\n");
        lista = api.Decode(inputData);
        lista.add(conexion.EstadoByHash(web3, txHash));
        if (lista.size() != 0 || lista != null) {
            return lista;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error 222-3 interno en el Metodo ObtenerByHash en la clase Conexion.java : " + e);
    } finally {
        inputData = null;
        lista = null;
        txHash = null;
    }
    ArrayList<String> err = new ArrayList<>();
    err.add("Error 222-3");
    return null;
}`

Comment: ¿En que linea te da el error?

Comment: @JDev No me muestra la linea porque este error lo vi en log del tomcat por el try-catch que tengo en el codigo y solo me muestra esto "Error 222-3 interno en el Metodo ObtenerByHash en la clase Conexion.java : java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present"

Comment: ¿Pudiera ser que `conexion.EstadoByHash(web3, txHash)` devuelva null ?

Comment: Puede ser porque solo me fijado con las variables txHash y InputData, pondré una condición que me muestre si esta vació, gracias por la sugerencia